# MapReduce Mrunit error

Tags: hadoop, mrunit

I'm a new in Hadoop. Yesterday I followed the book and used JUnit as the apper unit test for meteorological data. But there were some problems.

This is my pom file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-minicluster</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

and this are problems:

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found class
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskInputOutputContext, but interface was
>   expected

Look forward  and thank you for your answer！

Comment: @vipul gulhane I hadn't tried WorldCount

Comment: please check I Have added my pom.xml

Comment: OLD JAR:-public interface Mapper<K1, V1, K2, V2> extends JobConfigurable, Closeable {

}


NEW JAR:- public class Mapper<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT> {}

 I just changed the jar from hadoop1 to hadoop2 and after that all the my unit test cases ran successfully. 
 
 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRUNIT-156

Comment: @vipul gulhane thank you give me that Link，you resolve my problem ,thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that in Hadoop 2.x, there is not Hadoop-core, so the right pom is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding different jar version.
I changed the from `mrunit-1.1.0.jar`  to `mrunit-0.9.0-incubating-hadoop2.jar`
OLD JAR:-
`public interface Mapper<K1, V1, K2, V2> extends JobConfigurable, Closeable { }` NEW JAR:-

```
 public class Mapper<KEYIN, VALUEIN, KEYOUT, VALUEOUT> {}
```

I just changed the jar from hadoop1 to hadoop2 and after that all the my unit test cases ran successfully.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRUNIT-156

```
     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.org</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- JDK Tools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <version>1.8.0_73</version>
            <systemPath>${JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hadoop Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hadoop Mapreduce Client Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0-incubating</version>
            <classifier>hadoop1</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0-incubating</version>
            <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Emmm ..No effect .

Comment: @ PC12138, here is my pom.xml